# Windows 10 - Run a command when connecting to a device, say, a dock or monitor [Automate]

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

In Windows 10, is there a way to run cmd/powershell commands automatically when PC is connected to a particular device like a dock? (Like connecting a particular device triggers a command)

I want to do something like this-

```
If [device1 connected] -> Run Command A
If [device1 disconnected] -> Run Command B
If [device2 connected] -> Run Command C
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/ describes using task scheduler to run a script on an Event Log event: anything that creates a notification in an event log can be used as the trigger.

> Find an Event in an Event log: note the Log name and the Event ID.

> Give your task a name in the General tab, and then click Triggers and then click New. Select "On an event": select the Log noted above, and enter the Event ID.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-monitor-and-respond-to-events-on-your-server/ describes
using WMI as an permanent event consumer: event consumers can be linked to many Windows Events, including connect/disconnect events, not just Event Log events, but isn't as self-evident.

> $consumerPath = Set-WmiInstance -Class ActiveScriptEventConsumer

Comment: `help Set-WmiInstance -Full` New CIM cmdlets, introduced Windows PowerShell 3.0, perform the same tasks as the WMI cmdlets. The CIM cmdlets comply with WS-Management
    (WSMan) standards and with the Common Information Model (CIM) standard. this enables cmdlets to use the same techniques to manage
    Windows-based computers and those running other operating systems. Instead of using `Set-WmiInstance`, consider using the `Set-CimInstance`
    (/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/set-ciminstance) or [New-CimInstance](/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/new-ciminstance)cmdlets.